# Modify slinghttpresponse through wrapper

Tags: filter, aem, servlet-filters, sling

I am trying to override default sendredirect funtionality in AEM.

I would like to redirect to https urls from my server.

FOr the same I have implemented a sling filter. Implemented SlingHttpServletResponseWrapper class and overridden  sendredirect function.

However, in filter when I try to

final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = (ModifyLocResponse) response;

At runtime I get

org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter$RewriterResponse cannot be cast to com.adobe.acs.samples.filters.wrappers.ModifyLocResponse

Comment: Please add the code for `ModifyLocResponse` and the filter where you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of casting, try instantiating it by something like this:

```
final SlingHttpServletResponse slingResponse = new ModifyLocResponse(response);
```

Of course you'll need to make sure the constructor for that class has this pattern too:

```
class ModifyLocResponse extends SlingHttpServletResponseWrapper {
    public ModifyLocResponse(SlingHttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }
    ...
}
```